# EJB override injection of abstract bean

Tags: java, ejb

I have an abstract bean with injected ISomeOtherBean interface:

```
public abstract class AbstractBean {
    @EJB ISomeOtherBean myService;
}
```

The ISomeOtherBean is interface. He have many implementations, for example: SomeBeanA, SomeBeanB...

```
@Stateless
public class SomeBeanA implements ISomeOtherBean {
}

@Stateless
public class SomeBeanB implements ISomeOtherBean {
}
```

How can I inject concrete implementation of ISomeOtherBean inside some implementation of the AbstractBean?

```
@Stateless
public class BeanImpl extends AbstractBean {
    // how write that I want inject SomeBeanB which implements ISomeOtherBean 
}
```

First i tried to inject concrete implementation inside BeanImpl, then I passed it to additional method of superclass (Abstractbean) which writed it to field myService.
But this solution is bad for me. I remember Spring has ability to pass some beans to constructor of given bean. But it was inside XML configuration. I want something like this, but with EJB and annotation configurations.

Anyone knows how do it?

Comment: Spring supports annotation-based configuration, and it most likely supports EJB annotations. But using Spring means you will need to switch to it completely, and abandon EJB.

Comment: You can always use JNDI lookup: `ISomeOtherBean someBeanA = (ISomeOtherBean ) new InitialContex().lookup("java:module/SomeBeanA")`

Comment: Have you tried to specify this via descriptor: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/injecting_different_implementations_into_an